# how to include image in json object and how to retrieve it

Tags: javascript, json

please help me in solving how to store image in json file and how retrive it 
i have already tried . but i am not able to

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var jsonURL = "data/data.json";
  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json)
  {
    var imgList= "";

    $.each(json.products, function () {

      imgList += '<li><img src= "' + this.imgPath + '"></li>';
    });
   $('#dvProdList').append(imgList);
  
  });


});
```

```html
<div>
    <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

it here

Comment: what does your `this` in the `each` evaluates to?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite well. Just change your HTML

```
<div>
    <ul id="dvProdList"></ul>
</div>
```

And then in your javascript (check how [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) statement works in jquery):

```
 $.each(json.products, function (index, product) {
      imgList += '<li><img src= "' + product.imgPath + '"></li>';
 });
 $('#dvProdList').html(imgList);
```

Make shure your image paths are ok and you are loading the json correctly.